# SIGSEGV when calling solve() in CPLEX

Tags: cplex

As the title suggests, Java Runtime Environment throws me a simple segmentation error after I'm calling solve ().

I don't understand if it is an incompatibility problem with the JRE or something else.
The code runs on a Docker container, especially on Linux Alpine distro.
The same code on Windows does not create problems.

Here is a screen shot of the error:

[image]

That's the code:

```
    System.out.println("1");
    cplex = new IloCplex();
    System.out.println("2");
    IloIntVar z = cplex.intVar(0, Integer.MAX_VALUE, "z");
    IloIntVar[] x = new IloIntVar[hotels.size()];
    IloIntVar[][] y = new IloIntVar[maxNumberOfRooms][hotels.size()];
    IloIntVar[][] g = new IloIntVar[maxNumberOfRooms][hotels.size()];
    IloLinearNumExpr linearNumExpr2 = cplex.linearNumExpr();
    IloLinearNumExpr linearNumExpr4 = cplex.linearNumExpr();
    IloLinearIntExpr linearIntExpr = cplex.linearIntExpr();
    IloLinearNumExpr objective = cplex.linearNumExpr();
    List<IloRange> constraints = new ArrayList<>();
    IloIntExpr[] intExprs = new IloIntExpr[hotels.size()];
    List<HashMap<String, Object>> hotelRooms = new LinkedList<>();
    double newScalarProduct = 0.0;
    double yMax = days;
    double yMin = 0.1;

    for (int i = 0; i < hotels.size(); ++i) {
        IloLinearNumExpr linearNumExpr1 = cplex.linearNumExpr();
        IloLinearNumExpr linearNumExpr3 = cplex.linearNumExpr();
        x[i] = cplex.intVar(0, Integer.MAX_VALUE, ("x" + i));
        linearIntExpr.addTerm(1, x[i]);

        for (int j = 0; j < maxNumberOfRooms; ++j) {
            y[j][i] = cplex.intVar(0, days, ("y" + j + i));
            g[j][i] = cplex.intVar(0, 1, ("g" + j + i));
            linearNumExpr1.addTerm(pricePerNight[j][i], y[j][i]);
            linearNumExpr3.addTerm(places[j][i], g[j][i]);
        }

        objective.addTerm(certainties.get(i), x[i]);
        linearNumExpr2.add(linearNumExpr1);
        linearNumExpr4.add(linearNumExpr3);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < hotels.size(); ++i) {
        IloLinearIntExpr linearIntExpr1 = cplex.linearIntExpr();

        for (int j = 0; j < maxNumberOfRooms; ++j) {
            linearIntExpr1.addTerm(1, y[j][i]);
            constraints.add((IloRange) cplex.addGe(y[j][i], cplex.prod(yMin, g[j][i])));
            constraints.add((IloRange) cplex.addLe(y[j][i], cplex.prod(yMax, g[j][i])));
        }

        intExprs[i] = cplex.abs(cplex.diff(x[i], 1));
        constraints.add((IloRange)cplex.addEq(linearIntExpr1, x[i]));
    }

    for (Double scalarProduct : solToDiscard) {
        IloLinearNumExpr linearNumExpr_ = cplex.linearNumExpr();
        linearNumExpr_.addTerms(coefficients, x);
        constraints.add(cplex.addGe(cplex.abs(cplex.diff(linearNumExpr_, scalarProduct)), 0.001));
    }

    constraints.add((IloRange)cplex.addEq(cplex.sum(intExprs), z));
    constraints.add(cplex.addLe(linearIntExpr, days));
    constraints.add(cplex.addLe(linearNumExpr2, budget));
    constraints.add(cplex.addGe(linearNumExpr4, numPeople));
    cplex.addMaximize(cplex.diff(objective, z));

    System.out.println("3");
    if (cplex.solve()) {
        System.out.println("8");
        int realDays = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j  < hotels.size(); ++j) {
            realDays += cplex.getValue(x[j]);
            System.out.println("5");
            for (int i = 0; i < maxNumberOfRooms; ++i) {
                if (cplex.getValue(y[i][j]) > 0) {
                    HashMap<String, Object> hm = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                    hm.put("Room", hotelsRooms.get(hotels.get(j).getId()).get(i));
                    hm.put("DaysInRoom", cplex.getValue(y[i][j]));
                    System.out.println("y" + i + j + " :" + cplex.getValue(y[i][j]));
                    hotelRooms.add(hm);
                }
            }
        }
```

Clearly it prints the 3, but it doesn't prints the 8...
I also tried to increase the heap dedicated to the process, but nothing ...

Comment: If you look at the [detailed system requirements](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/detailed-system-requirements-ibm-ilog-cplex-optimization-studio) for CPLEX, you'll find that Alpine Linux is not officially supported, nor is OpenJDK. With that said, you may still be able to get this to work. Can you show us a gdb backtrace? That may help to pinpoint the problem.

Comment: It looks like you cross-posted this question [here](https://community.ibm.com/community/user/datascience/communities/community-home/digestviewer/viewthread?MessageKey=d1e24099-7537-4c2c-859c-f9c15b3608cb&CommunityKey=ab7de0fd-6f43-47a9-8261-33578a231bb7&tab=digestviewer#bmd1e24099-7537-4c2c-859c-f9c15b3608cb). In the future, please don't do that as it can waste the time of CPLEX developers. Both forums are monitored, so posting to one or the other will suffice.

Comment: @rkersh Thanks a lot, now I installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with a jdk-8u251. I read that linux Alpine uses stack smashing technology, could it be for that?

Comment: @rkersh Ok, next time, I will post on one of the two.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Alpine Linux, but it appears that it uses `muslc` (a minimalist libc). There is some explanation [here](https://wiki.musl-libc.org/faq.html) about why crashes can occur. As mentioned, CPLEX isn't supported on Alpine so this is not something that was tested. You could create a request for enhancement (RFE) [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rfe) if you think Alpine Linux support is important.